# MySql Insert Ignore performance

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server-ce

I have to insert 90Mb of data into MySql Tables and I'm using INSERT IGNORE command to avoid the exception of duplicate key. The performance are 8 records a second but it seems very slow. Could I fast it up?

p.s. I'm inserting record per record since i read data from an sql compact database

```
using (SqlCeConnection sqlConnection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionstrCe))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCeCommand cmdCe = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
                {
                    {

                        mySQLConnection.Open();

                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> t in tablesCeNames) //reading the tables property from the dictionary - column names and datatypes
                        {

                            string tableData = t.Key; 
                            List<string> columnData = t.Value;
//get the values from the table I want to transfer the data
                                cmdText = "SELECT * FROM " + tableData;
//compose the mysql command
                                cmdCe.CommandText = cmdText;

                                SqlCeDataReader dataReader = cmdCe.ExecuteReader(); //read
//InsertTable is a method that get the datareader and convert all the data from this table in a list array with the values to insert
                                inputValues = InsertTables(dataReader);


                                MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction transakcija;
                                transakcija = mySQLConnection.BeginTransaction();

                                worker.ReportProgress(4, inputValues.Count);

                                foreach (string val in inputValues)//foreach row of values of the data table
                                {
                                    cmdSqlText = "INSERT IGNORE INTO " + tableData + "("; //compose the command for sql

                                    foreach (string cName in columnData)  //forach column in a table
                                    {
                                        string[] data = cName.Split(' ');
                                        if (!data[0].ToString().Equals("Id"))
                                        {
                                            cmdSqlText += data[0].ToString() + ","; //write the column names of the values that will be inserted  
                                        }
                                    }
                                    cmdSqlText = cmdSqlText.TrimEnd(',');
                                    cmdSqlText += ") VALUES (";
//val contains the values of this current record that i want to insert
                                    cmdSqlText += val;  //final command with insert ignore and the values of one record
                                    if (!val.Equals(""))
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(cmdSqlText, mySQLConnection, transakcija).ExecuteNonQuery(); //execute insert on sql database
                                            WriteToTxt("uspješno upisano u mysql" + t.Key);
                                        }
                                        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException sqlEx)
                                        {
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                if (TablicaSveOK)
                                {
                                    transakcija.Commit();

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    transakcija.Rollback();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (mySQLConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                        {
                            mySQLConnection.Close();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: One way would be to build a string builder in your loop and do the insert outside...this will take some of the heat off from hitting the database for every record

Comment: @Sam you mean insert a group of record at time?

Comment: Probably your code could be otpmized a lot, but without seeing it.....

Comment: that is right, it saves you hitting db every time and does a bulk insert

Comment: Further to the point made by @Sam , I do this fairly often. Possibly the easiest way is to knock up a class to do the insert. Instantiate an instance of that class. For each record you pass the row to the object, and it decides if it has enough rows to add. If not it adds the row to a store of awaiting rows, if there are enough rows it does your INSERT IGNORE for all those rows at once, then wipes out the store of awaiting rows. When all the rows are processed you destroy the object, and in the destruct method of the class you do the final inserts.

Answer (score 1):

What about getting the data from Sql to a file and use LOAD DATA?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather then sending multiple calls you can send one call to insert all records. Insert it like this

```
insert into your table(col1, col2)
SELECT 'Name1', 'Location1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Name2', 'Location2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Name3', 'Location3'
```

A part from this it is possible that your code is the bottle neck rather than the insert statement. So i would recommend you to first check where the problem lies and then go for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The latest MySql.Connector has a class called [MySqlBulkLoader](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html) that could be used to call the LOAD DATA syntax of MySql in a more NET oriented way. The class requires a comma separated value file to load from and is extremely fast.

So your job would be to read all of your Sql Compact records in a datatable and then, using a streamwriter or a specialized CSV Writer write down everything in a file.

Then the code to load your data in a MySql table is simple like this

```
string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=........";
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
     MySqlBulkLoader bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn);
     bl.TableName = "yourdestinationtable";
     bl.FieldTerminator = "\t";
     bl.LineTerminator = "\n";
     bl.FileName = "path_to_your_comma_separated_value_file";
     try
     {
        conn.Open();
        int count = bl.Load();
     }
}
```

Comment: i have a lot of duplicated value that I don't need to insert is there a problem using this bulkLoader?

Comment: You could insert all of your data in a separate temp table and then run a stored procedure that reconciles the data. All of this will be run on the server and thus will not impact the time required to load the data